# appending an input to a HTML form with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am trying to append an input to a HTML with JQuery form before sending it with AJAX but it does not gets appended because I see in the back end that the field is null. here is my HTML form:

```
 <form class="basketForm loginForm" id="@formId" autocomplete="off" captcha="false">
        <div class="newRegister-addMobileNumber">
            <div class="newRegister-formBox">
                <div class="formElement newRegister-input">
                    <input id="@userNameInputId" type="text" name="EmailOrPhoneNumber" class="form-control persianDigitInput" placeholder="تلفن همراه" >

                </div>
                <div class="newRegister-button">
                    <button type="submit" class="animateBtn greenAnimateBtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        send
                        </button>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and here is my JavaScript code:

```
loadValidation: function (classId) {
//I suspect that this part is not reading the url correctly
        var currentUrl = window.location.href;
        console.log(currentUrl);
        var self = this;
        $(classId)
           .validate({
               rules: {
                   EmailOrPhoneNumber: {
                       required: true,
                       regex: $utils.regex.EmailOrPhoneNumber
                   },
                   Password: {
                       required: true
                   }
               },
               messages: {
                   EmailOrPhoneNumber: {
                       required: $utils.messages.user.required_EmailOrPhoneNumber,
                       regex: $utils.messages.other.notValid_EmailPhoneNumberFormat
                   },
                   Password: {
                       required: $utils.messages.user.required_Password
                   }
               },
               submitHandler: function (form) {
                   var $form = $(form);
                   var validator = $form.data("validator");
                   if (self.requireCaptcha(classId)) {
                       var captcha = $(classId + " input[name='CaptchaImage']").val();
                       if (captcha.length <= 0) {
                           validator.showErrors({
                               CaptchaImage: $utils.messages.other.requreid_CaptchaImage
                           });
                           return;
                       }
                   }
                   if (!validator || !$form.valid())
                       return;
                   $("#returnUrl").val($("#returnUrl").val() + window.location.hash);
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "/Account/Login",
                       datatype: "json",
                       type: "POST",
// this is the part where the input should be appended to the form
                       addurl: function () {
                           if ( currentUrl == "http://localhost:59746/Account/Register/") {
                               console.log(currentUrl)
                               $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                                   .attr('name', "ReturnUrl")
                               .attr('value', "regurl")
                                   .appendTo(".basketForm.loginForm");}


      },
```

any ideas why it is not working? I have also tried removing the . between basketForm.loginForm and replace it with a space, but it did not work either

Comment: What is `addurl` parameter? I can't find from [offcial jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) ..?

Comment: it is a function that I have defined

Comment: Yes, but jQuery.ajax doesn't handle a parameter named `addurl` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with your code.

There is no `addurl` method on `$.ajax` that's why your form field is not appended to DOM (Refer [$.ajax API](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). There is a `beforeSend` method on `$.ajax` API, however it is used to modify the jqXHR object before it is sent.

Argument name to your method `loadValidation` should be `formClass` or `formId` because `classId` makes no sense and please format your code nicely, it looks really bad right now.

You can append your field to form just before sending ajax request.

Following is the fiddle which appends the form field before sending data to server:

Working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3s97qkun/)

Answer (score 0):

you can serialize input values before sending to server, and append any other parameter to it like this

```
// serialize all inputs inside .loginForm
var formData = $('.loginForm :input').serializeArray();
// add other data when on specific address
if (currentUrl == "http://localhost:59746/Account/Register/") {
  formData.push({ name: "ReturnUrl", value: "regurl" });
}

// post with formData
$.post('/Account/Login',formData,function(responseData){
  // do something here with responseData
},'json');
```

**EDIT :**
from the context of your code, try to change your ajax request lines shown below with above script

```
$.ajax({
                       url: "/Account/Login",
                       datatype: "json",
                       type: "POST",
// this is the part where the input should be appended to the form
                       addurl: function () {
                           if ( currentUrl == "http://localhost:59746/Account/Register/") {
                               console.log(currentUrl)
                               $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                                   .attr('name', "ReturnUrl")
                               .attr('value', "regurl")
                                   .appendTo(".basketForm.loginForm");}
})
```

Comment: can you put the code in the context of my code? I am newbie in javascript and front end in general